# Search path for lisp files

Tags: init-file, load-path

When starting emacs using the initialisation file

**/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/.emacs**

what is the default search path for lisp files if I use the default value of `load-path` (I don't change the value)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your build of Emacs. You can get this information by starting Emacs using the initialisation file you mentioned, and invoking `C-h v load-path RET`. The help window will display the current value of the variable `load-path`, which is the default one if your configuration file does not change it. Alternatively, you can directly evaluate the variable using `M-: load-path RET`.